# How to check if index is the last one in the array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Hey I'm trying to create a if statement that goes through the entire array and then asks if that index is the last one in the array.

This is what I have so far.

Code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  { // Called for each cell made

  if notificationList[indexPath.row] == notificationList.last! {

        print("At last index")

   }
}
```

UPDATE:

Actually I think this works but I will take other answers

Comment: `if indexPath.row == notificationList.count - 1 { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  { 

  if indexPath.row == notificationList.count - 1 {

        print("At last index")

   }
}
```

Comment: its not working for some reason if I can get it to work ill mark as correct